# Как удалить исходные файлы после перемещения

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive

пример [отсюда](https://www.labnol.org/file-uploads-folder-google-forms-201226)
скрипт копирует файл в указанную папку. мне нужно чтобы исходные файлы удалялись

```
const onFormSubmit = ({ response } = {}) => {
  try {
    // Get a list of all files uploaded with the response
    const files = response
      .getItemResponses()
      // We are only interested in File Upload type of questions
      .filter((itemResponse) => itemResponse.getItem().getType().toString() === 'FILE_UPLOAD')
      .map((itemResponse) => itemResponse.getResponse())
      // The response includes the file ids in an array that we can flatten
      .reduce((a, b) => [...a, ...b], []);

    if (files.length > 0) {
      // Each form response has a unique Id
      const subfolderName = response.getId();
      const parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(UPLOAD_FOLDER);
      const subfolder = parentFolder.createFolder(subfolderName);
      files.forEach((fileId) => {
        // Move each file into the custom folder
        DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).moveTo(subfolder);
      });
    }
  } catch (f) {
    Logger.log(f);
  }
};
```

пробовал 2 варианта, исходные файлы на месте, а в UPLOAD_FOLDER попадает только 1-й файл

**1**

```
  files.forEach((fileId) => {
    // Move each file into the custom folder
    DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).moveTo(subfolder);
    DriveApp.removeFile(fileId)  
  });
```

**2**

```
  files.forEach((fileId) => {
    // Move each file into the custom folder
    DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).makeCopy(subfolder);
    DriveApp.removeFile(fileId)  
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы удалить файл физически, необходимо поместить его в корзину:

```js
const file = DriveApp.getFileById('ZZZ');
file.setTrashed(true);
```